# Hyperlink not showing correct route in href

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've got the following route added to our route table:

```
       map.Route(new Route("Car/Delete/{id}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Car",
                action = "Delete",
            }), new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

In my Car.cshtml I've got:

@Html.ActionLink("X", "Delete", "Car", @Model.Car.CarId, null)

But when the link renders, its href is set to the same url that I'm on (page I'm no) and not set to /Car/Delete/10 (10 is a carId).

Not sure why the hyperlink isn't showing the right route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
@Html.ActionLink("X", "Delete", "Car", new { id = @Model.Car.CarId }, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Bassam has answered your question already, so I won't add my identical version.

However, what you are doing is very bad practice (at least on the surface as I can't see your controller action). You are issuing a delete action via a `HttpGet` request on the URL, i.e.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/Car/Delete/10
```

this is gonna be asking for big trouble, unless you of course have a rather elegant '2nd level' `HttpPost` going on via a confirmation message from said get request.

i just wanna point this out as it's very dangerous looking.